# WPF windows that have the AllowsTransparency property set to true

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In my WPF application I set the AllowsTransparency property to be false (AllowsTransparency =“False”).

The only thing that I have been notice is: when I set also Background="Transparent" -> i will get black background (instead of Transparent Background.

What I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Which .net framework version are you using ?

Comment: Can you update to .NET 4.7.2 ?

Comment: This question is exactly the same as [the one you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58349495). It is against Stack Overflow guidelines to delete and repost an exact copy of a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can’t do this type of interop with AllowsTransparency=“True”. It’s a restriction in how it was implemented at the framework level.

This same restriction applies to things like the WPF web browser control, etc.